# Better way to write repetitive function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation function I've created to scroll my webpage horizontally, this works fine however I'm guessing it could be written much better. Can anybody give me advice on what I could be doing logic wise to minimise my code?

**jQuery**

```
$('.sectionOne').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-one').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionTwo').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-two').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionThree').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' :-$('.section-three').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionFour').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-four').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionFive').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-five').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionSix').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-six').offset().left
    });       
});

$('.sectionSeven').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('nav').find('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.section-seven').offset().left
    });       
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
        <nav>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-one" class="active sectionOne">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-two" class="sectionTwo">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-three" class="sectionThree">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-four" class="sectionFour">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-five" class="sectionFive">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-six" class="sectionSix">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-section="section-seven" class="sectionSeven">7</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
```

Comment: This is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com but there's little point in giving individual elements a unique class. Give them a common class, and use `this` to reference the current element.

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn;t aware of codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

It looks very redundant. How about something like:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('nav a.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 

    $('.scene').animate({
        'marginLeft' : -$('.' + $(this).attr('data-section')).offset().left
    });       
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. However, I would use `.data( 'section' )` instead of `.attr( 'data-section' )`, should the data in this attribute be changed in the life of the page.